# Interface Builder not Sizing Correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I am relatively new to iOS programming, and I am struggling with interface builder. Apparently, this IB thing is supposed to be easy, but when I build things, they don't match up in the app. Can anyone help me out(thanks in advance)?

Iterface Builder:

[image: InterfaceBuilder]

and in the simulator:

[image: Simulator Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had to add the whole view hierarchy to a window to make it work. Now my view hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Under "Simulated Metrics" in the Attributes Inspector, change the "Status Bar" dropdown to "Translucent Black" (in this case). Your IB view should match what you're seeing in the simulator after that.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. Let me see if I can try a couple other things. Er, now it just cuts off some of the text from the bottom :-(

Comment: You'll have to make sure whatever the text is in isn't getting pushed down. It probably needs resized.

Comment: Turns out I needed to add the view to a window -- I really appreciate your answer though, thanks for responding.